# ReferenceError for Data Service Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to build my first MEAN stack app (an online cookbook), but I appear to be running into some issues in Angular between the service that fetches recipe data from my API (RecipeDataService) and my "recipe detail" Component.

Every time I try to load a recipe's detail view none of the information from the service appears. I also get the following error in the browser's JS console:

```
ReferenceError: RecipeDataService is not defined
at Object.onHandleError (core.js:4770)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError (zone.js:392)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask (zone.js:444)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount (zone.js:461)
at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount (zone.js:285)
at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
at HTMLAnchorElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)
```

Here's what I know about the issue so far:

- The API endpoints themselves function as expected. The two endpoints that are being used by the RecipeDataService right now pull a list of recipes and detailed information about a recipe respectively.
- The "recipe list" component is able to use the recipe data service to pull a list of recipes without error.
- The error only appears when the "detail" Component's HTML attempts to display recipe information that was fetched by the service. In other words the RecipeDataService can still be imported, listed as a provider, and have its method invoked; the error only appears when its data gets included in the template.

Here is the TypeScript for the RecipeDataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class RecipeDataService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * Gets summary info on all Recipes from the database.
   */
  getAllRecipes() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/recipes');
  }

  /**
   * Gets a single Recipe from the database.
   */
  readRecipe(id: String) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/recipes/' + id);
  }
}
```

Here is the TypeScript for the recipe detail component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {RecipeDataService} from "../recipe-data.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'recipe-detail',
  templateUrl: './recipe-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [RecipeDataService]
})
export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private recipeId;
  private recipe;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private recipeDataService: RecipeDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    // Pull the Recipe ID as a parameter from the Route
    this.recipeId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    // Then look up the Recipe with the database service
    this.getRecipe();
  }

  private getRecipe() {
    this.recipeDataService.readRecipe(this.recipeId).subscribe(
      data => {this.recipe = data},
      err => console.error(err));
  }

  navigateToRecipeList(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/recipe-list');
  }

}
```

And here is the Component's HTML template

```
<h3>{{recipeId}}<!-- Does not cause an error --></h3>
<p>Name: {{recipe.name}}<!-- This is the problem statement --></p>
...
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try using this in the template and see if the error resolves: `{{ recipe?.name }}`

Comment: why your data-bound properties are TypeScript `private` properties. Angular never binds to a TypeScript `private` property. it must be typescript `public` property

Comment: what does `console.log(this.recipe.hasOwnProperty('name'));` shows?

Comment: @bc1105 That seemed to resolve the issue. What exactly did that do?

Comment: @Vikas `VM1021:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:25`

Comment: `recipe?.name` will not attempt to access `name` until `recipe` resolves.

Comment: `?.` [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) @Michael you need to put the console inside subscribe anyways your issue is resolved. Happy coding :)

Comment: I read the documentation page for the ?. operator, but I still don't understand why I need to use it in this instance. What exactly is preventing me from using normal dot notation if the attributes to `this.recipe` exist?

Comment: Also @Vikas when you say "put the console inside subscribe" could you explain in more detail? Thank you.

Comment: I meant `data => {this.recipe=data;console.log(this.recipe.hasOwnProperty('name')); }`

Comment: @Vikas That returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the RecipeDataService as a provider at the module level